# What happens when a player announces a check while there is an active bet?

Tags: rules, live, casino

Example situation:

- The flop comes.
- Alice checks.
- Bob pushes forward a small bet.
- Eve (perhaps misreading) says "check."

Does Eve have to:

1. fold
2. call
3. act again by announcing a fold, call, or raise

I expect in a friendly home game, option #3 applies. What about in casinos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation you have described Eve has all options available to her, as you mentioned in item 3 on what she can do, even in a casino. In general unless action changes it is binding, I.E. Bob's bet has changed action so Eve has all available options to her.

It is important to note, if Eve keeps doing this in a casino she may get a warning and even a penalty if it continues.

Comment: I think it also depends on whether she checks after Bob bets. If after, then its an invalid (and moot) action, and shes still required to take a valid action, but shes not affecting the game in any way. If she checks before Bob bets, then shes giving Bob information, which should be penalised (or given warning) in some way.

Comment: This is a good addition from Sakon, often from when I was a dealer I'd just let the player, give them a little bit of slack for the first or second time. But absolutely if it keeps happening they should be warned and then penalised.

Comment: Do tell, what penalty? Maybe a tournament some place, but in a cash game I haver never seen any kind  of penalty. (Never seen any kind except for the kind people occasionally are 86ed for. You know fighting clearly cheating etc.)